# ThemeManager does not change the style of the control

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm tryingn the `ThemeManager` of `MahApp` and all working well, more or less. The less part is a strange situation that doesn't change the color of my control. When I apply the new accent the text color change, but for example on the `GroupBox` I see the `Background` still white. This is my `App.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatButton.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.ListView.xaml" />

    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

then I change the app style in this way:

```
 public class AccentColorMenuData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush BorderColorBrush { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush ColorBrush { get; set; }

    private ICommand changeAccentCommand;

    public ICommand ChangeAccentCommand
    {
        get { return changeAccentCommand ?? (changeAccentCommand = new SimpleCommand
        {
            CanExecuteDelegate = x => true, ExecuteDelegate = x => DoChangeTheme(x) });
        }
    }

    protected virtual void DoChangeTheme(object sender)
    {
        var theme = ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
        var accent = ThemeManager.GetAccent(Locale.GetEnColor(Name));
        ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current.Resources, accent, theme.Item1);
    }
}
```

I followed the example of mahapp. As I said only the controls doesn't change the background color, all the other things working.

Maybe 'cause I split my UI in `UserControl`? Thanks for any help..

Comment: Why would you expect the background to change if you are only changing the accent color?  You have to change the theme to change the background color.  For example, replace `theme.Item1` with `ThemeManager.GetInverseAppTheme(theme.Item1)` to switch from light to dark (or vice versa).

Comment: @MikeStrobel I did what you said, the controls like "GroupBox and other" still is blank, but the background of my application change to black

Comment: What do you mean 'blank'?  What is actually happening, and what is it that you _expect_ to happen?

Comment: sorry I mean "white", anyway, I thouth that this problem is relative to materialdesigninxaml that doesn't support the theme manager, I'm not secure at all

Comment: You still haven't stated what you _expect_ the results to be, or how the actual results differ from what you expected.  It's unclear what the problem is, because you haven't stated the problem.